# Getting Windows Media Player DLNA services to share media located on a network share?

Tags: windows-media-player, dlna

I share the media on my desktop to all my DLNA capable devices via windows media player in Windows 7.  I notice that only the media that physically resides on my desktop is being shared.  Items that i've imported to the library, but physically reside on my server, does not get shared.

Does anyone have a work around for this?